# Which part of this relationship WillCascadeOnDelete(true)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This is what I have today:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.DealDevice)
    .WithRequired(c => c.User)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

What I would like is to have the related `DealDevice` rows be deleted if the user is deleted so that I can just delete the user and have everything related go away.

Can I just change `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` to `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` or will that delete the user if the deal is deleted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct: to cascade deletes from `User` to `DealDevice` just use `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)`. It's not going to delete the `User` if a `DealDevice` is deleted, only the other way around.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.DealDevice)
    .WithRequired(c => c.User)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Note: you don't have to specify the parameter to `WillCascadeOnDelete()` if you want to cascade deletes as there's an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696319%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) implicitly setting it to `true`.